# JSON - Model + Implementation in Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I've watched quite a lot videos about parsing JSON in Swift, but I just don't get it. I'm trying to get it the right way, meaning asynchronous way, so I don't block anything. I'm just very confused about this array in dictionary in a dictionary in array and so on structure of JSON and I don't get how to parse it properly.

I want to understand how to model my app using Struct or Class as a separate file, create an instance of it and parse JSON's in a UTTableView.

What's confusing for me is the fact that I don't get how to structure everything (model + implementation).

For example, I've been playing around with this JSON http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/66/fixtures

I want to make a model out of the Fixtures of that team, so make a model, implement/parse JSON and populate Tableview.

Example of my code so far:

**In my Model (which is a struct) I have this:**

```
  struct RestApiManager {

    var awayTeamName: NSString
    var homeTeamName: String

    var dateOfTheMatch: NSDate
    var leagueRound: Int

//    var goalsHomeTeam: Int
//    var goalsAwayTeam: Int
//    
//    var clubIcons: String


    init(fixturesDictionary: NSDictionary) {

        let allFixtures = fixturesDictionary["fixtures"] as! NSArray

        awayTeamName = fixturesDictionary["awayTeamName"] as! NSString
        homeTeamName = fixturesDictionary["homeTeamName"] as! String
        dateOfTheMatch = fixturesDictionary["date"] as! NSDate
        leagueRound = fixturesDictionary["matchday"] as! Int


    }
```

**In the Viewcontroller** I have this (as I was just testing the JSON and if its returns data correctly, well, it doesn't - it crashes and the error says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and I don't know why):

```
let fixturesUrl = NSURL(string: "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/66/fixtures")

    let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(fixturesUrl!) { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        // If there's no errors then unwrap the optional values
        if (error == nil) {

            // Creates a data object based on the information of the "location"
            let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: location) // "location" is the file that's stored on the disk

            // Convert the dataObject into a JSON object
            let fixturesDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

            // Instance of RestApiManager 

            let restApiManager = RestApiManager(fixturesDictionary: fixturesDictionary)

            println(restApiManager.dateOfTheMatch)

        }

    }

    downloadTask.resume()
```

If anyone could show me how I would be really grateful.

Comment: This means you are unwrapping an optional value with an exclamation mark which is nil. Maybe `fixturesUrl` or `dataObject` or `fixturesDictionary`. (It's the last one I guess).

Comment: I suggest you use Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to parse your data is you use online tools.

**E.g.** http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

**Your Model:**

So, your `init()` method will looks like this

```
init(fixturesDictionary: NSDictionary) {

    let allFixtures = fixturesDictionary["fixtures"] as! NSArray
    for index in 0..<allFixtures.count{
         awayTeamName = fixturesDictionary[index]["awayTeamName"] as! NSString
         homeTeamName = fixturesDictionary[index]["homeTeamName"] as! String
         dateOfTheMatch = fixturesDictionary[index]["date"] as! String
         leagueRound = fixturesDictionary[index]["matchday"] as! Int
     }
}
```

Comment: That actually gives 2 errors for all of the properties in the for in loop: 

1) Cannot subscript a value of type "AnyObject?" with an index of type "String" (this is the error for AwayTeamName)
2) Cannot assign to immutable value of type NSString (this is the error for AwayTeamName again)

Comment: Have you cast `awayTeamName` as `AnyObject` ? @Swifter

Answer (score 0):

JSON data cannot contain NSDate objects. It contains: NSDictionary, NSArray, NSString, NSNumber (for numbers and boolean values) and NSNull. You'll have to look at the data that you receive to find out what format the server uses to report dates to you, and add code to convert a string to a date.

Apart from that, I really hope you are aware that whenever the JSON data doesn't match what you expect when you use as! , your app will crash. Because that's what as! means: "Please convert this for me, and if it doesn't work, please crash".

Answer (score 0):

Models generated against the JSON from http://www.json4swift.com

```
let fixturesUrl = NSURL(string: "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/66/fixtures")
let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
var fixtures : Array

let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(fixturesUrl!) { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

    // If there's no errors then unwrap the optional values
    if (error == nil) {

        // Creates a data object based on the information of the "location"
        let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: location) // "location" is the file that's stored on the disk

        // Convert the dataObject into a JSON object
        let fixturesDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

//Instantiate fixtures array from fixturesDictionary
     fixtures = Fixtures.modelsFromDictionaryArray(someDictionaryArrayFromJSON)

        println(fixtures[0].date)
        println(fixtures[0].homeTeamName)


    }

}

downloadTask.resume()
```

And thats pretty much it.